# How to select a checkbox jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my jquery object didn't get checked with `$('.checkall').checked = true ;`
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23Bt2/4/).
**UPDATE** : [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/23Bt2/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
$('.checkall').prop('checked',true);
```

Or:

```
$('.checkall')[0].checked = true ;
```

You would use `.prop()` to set the property of `checked` or directly covnert the jQuery element to `HTMLElement` and then directly set the value.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem of mixing jQuery, and DOM, methods. jQuery doesn't have access to the `.value` property of the node, instead use:

```
$('.checkall').prop('checked',true);
```

Reference:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 3):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('.checkall').prop('checked',true)
```